# Elementor page builder plugin not loading up all the way?

Tags: plugins, errors

I have PHP version 7.0
256M Memory limit.

My log is showing some errors:

```
JS: showing 3 of 3
JS: 2019-04-21 07:04:21 [error X 7][https://www.watsonwebsolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor.min.js?ver=2.5.14:2:83475] Cannot set property \'controls\' of undefined 
JS: 2019-04-21 07:08:29 [error X 1][https://www.watsonwebsolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor.min.js?ver=2.5.14:2:83465] Unable to set property \'controls\' of undefined or null reference 
JS: 2019-07-31 06:34:53 [error X 2][https://www.watsonwebsolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor.min.js?ver=2.6.7:7:49864] i is undefined
```

---

```
PHP: showing 1 of 1
PHP: 2019-07-31 05:20:44 [notice X 25][/home/watsonwe/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/core/documents-manager.php::411] Undefined offset: 0 [array (
  'trace' => '
#0: Elementor\Core\Logger\Manager -> shutdown()
',
)]
```

I have to launch Elementor in Safe Mode but the left sidebar keeps showing the loading animation.

Answer (score 1):

Had to remove a line of code from the footer of the theme.  Apparently, the contact form javascript is incompatible with Elementor.

```
  <script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/contact_me.js"></script>
```